# Finding a linear operator where $T$ maps $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\ker(T)=\text{im}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've visited other similar examples on the internet and this page but I cannot understand the content.

This is a question in part of my assignment along with show no such operator exists for the linear map of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. I have compiled an answer for the second half using the theorem of conservation of dimension. The first part is meant to be the easiest but I'm struggling in the course content and am lost at how to go about it.

For the second half I had

$$\dim(U)=\dim(\ker(T)) + \dim(\text{im}(T)),$$

therefore

$$\dim(U)= 2\dim(\text{im}(T)) = 2 \dim(\ker(T)).$$

Hence showing that $\dim(U)$ is always even. Hence we cannot have an operator for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ as the image and kernel could not be equal.

But for the first half I have been playing around with what I've found online.

I understand that for the kernel everything is mapped to zero
$$\ker(T) := \{u\in U: T(u)=0\}$$

and for $$\text{im}(T) :=\{T(u):u\in U\},$$

but I don't understand the connection.

There was an example concerning linear map to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ on this site but it did not make sense to me. It was where $T(x,y) = (y,0)$ and they said this satisfied it for the linear map $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
I played around with

$$T(x,y,z,w)=(x-z,y-w,z-x,w-y)$$

and

$$T(x,y,z,y)=(y,z,w,x).$$

I'm lost at the fundamentals and how to work out if the map in fact has $\text{im}(T)=\ker(T)$. Could someone please try and explain this to me?

Comment: $T(\Bbb R^4) = \operatorname{im}(T) = \ker(T)$, hence $T(T(\Bbb R^4)) = \{\vec 0\}$.

Comment: Hence, if $A\vec v = T(\vec v)$, then $A^2 = O$.

Comment: What if you tried $T(x,y,z,w) = (z,w,0,0)$?

Comment: Hi @matt, this is the form of something I want to try and get to, but I haven't been shown how to actually compute the kernel and image given a operator T. I know kernal sends everything to zero, but hence I'm a little confused to check if an operator works or not. Sorry, are you able to explain this a little further please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by choosing bases. But specifically, let $\{e_1, e_2\}$ be a basis for $\ker(T)$ (why is $\dim \ker (T) = 2$?) then extend this to a basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ for $\mathbb R^4$. We will attempt to define $T$ on this basis in a way that works.

First and foremost,

$$Te_1 = Te_2 = 0$$

by definition.

Secondly, you want $\mathrm{im}(T) = \ker(T)$ so

$$Te_3, Te_4 \in \mathrm{span}\{e_1, e_2\} \quad\text{(why?)}$$

and

$$\ker(T) = \mathrm{span}\{Te_3, Te_4\} \quad\text{(again, why?)}.$$

Now give an easy way to satisfy these two conditions and show that such a $T$ gives what you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response I think I'm making some sense of it now. So the dimension of the kernel will be 2 as the dimension overall is 4 (and we need the conservation of dim from my original post) therefore we require dim(ker(T)) = dim(im(T)). (Hence the only case can be dim(ker)=2)

Comment: Now I understand Te_1=Te_2 as it is in the kernel hence it sends them to zero. Also you've said that Te_3, Te_4 is in the span of {e_1,e_2} as to why, I think this would be because {e_1,e_2} is a basis for ker(T) and hence as we want the image to be the same as the kernel their elements must span the same set. Now you've said that ker(T)=span{Te_3,Te_4} I'm a little lost as I feel like this is taking me around in a circle or ive mis understood the one above. To satisfy these conditions I'm assuming we are only using e_3 and e_4 hence T(e1,e2,e3,e4)= (0,0,e_3,e_4) or am I on the wrong track

Comment: apologies for so many questions, I am just really struggling to wrap my head around the unit. I don't have a good foundation so I am struggling with the simple concepts and we haven't actually computed the ker and image in any examples from a simple linear operator, we are expected to know

Comment: @Jack $T$ applied to anything lies in $\mathrm{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$ because that's the kernel and $T$ maps onto the kernel. This justifies the first one. The second is saying that $Te_3, Te_4$ spans the kernel. You know that $\mathrm{im}(T) = \mathrm{span}\{Te_1, Te_2, Te_3, Te_4 \}$ and that $Te_1 = Te_2 = 0$ so this follows. You can also think of it as the first condition says that $\mathrm{im}(T) \subseteq \ker(T)$ and the second condition says that $\ker(T) \subseteq \mathrm{im}(T)$. You are on the right track to understanding this.

Comment: @Jack You cannot have $T(e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4) = (0, 0, e_3, e_4)$ because then $Te_3, Te_4 \not\in \ker(T) = \mathrm{span}\{e_1, e_2\}$. This is close to the right answer however, you just need to change some of the subscripts.

Comment: thank you I think those two things make a bit more sense now, thank you for the im(T) subset in ker explanation as I can relate to that a bit easier. I think I just realised that above where I said T(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4) = (0,0,e_3,e_4) this would mean that T(e_3)=e_3 but this couldn't occur as then e3 is not in the span of {e_1,e_2} therefore it is not in the kernel as required. Therefore I am assuming whatever my T operates on I will require this to translate to an e_1 and e_2 or 0 for it to be in the kernel. Is that correct? Hence I could have T(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)=(0,0,e_1,e_2)?

Comment: As this would imply T(e_1) = 0, T(e_2) = 0, T(e_3)=e_1 and T(e_4)=e_2. Now that would mean Te_3, Te_4 would be in the ker(T) = span{e_1,e_2} as they are equal to this is my thinking there correct? Thank you again

Comment: @Jack That's correct.

Comment: awesome, thank you much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the matrix corresponding to the transformation $T$.

We have $T(T(\Bbb R^4)) = T(\operatorname{im}(T)) = T(\ker(T)) = \{\vec 0\}$.

Therefore, $A^2 = O$.

Thus, $A$ is a nilpotent matrix with degree $2$.

Examples include $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&a&b\\0&0&0&c\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\a&0&0&0\\b&c&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and their similar matrices ($BAB^{-1}$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $T=\begin{bmatrix} T_{11} & T_{12} \\ T_{21} & T_{22} \end{bmatrix}$ where each $T_{ij}$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

If we set $T_{21} = T_{22} = 0$, then see that ${\cal R} T \bot \operatorname{sp} \{ e_3,e_4\}$, so we would like
${\cal R} T = \ker T = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,e_2\}$.

To achieve ${\cal R} T = \operatorname{sp} \{ e_1,e_2\}$ we can pick
$T_{12} = I$ and an arbitrary $T_{11}$ ($T_{11}=0$ will do).